# DOM Exception permission denied - periodic bckground sync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, service-worker

I have registered the JS file for the service worker by using React JS.
But, when I am trying to register the `periodic-background-sync` I am getting an error. Do I need to do any settings in google chrome?

The `status.state` flag is always retuning denied. I am not able to perform the background periodic sync.

Please see the below code

```
const status = await navigator.permissions.query({
    name: 'periodic-background-sync',
});
```

After checking the status, it is always returning "DENINED".

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue.  Chrome does a terrible job explaining why it is denied.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the PWA app first only after that chrome will grant you permission to use "periodic-background-sync".

Check out their [Demo App](https://webplatformapis.com/periodic_sync/periodicSync_improved.html).

After installing the APP try check the status

`navigator.permissions.query({ name: "periodic-background-sync" }).then((status)=>{ console.log(status)})`